# Why MySQL query cache not being used even it is enabled?

Tags: mysql, query-cache

```
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'have_query_cache';
+------------------+-------+
| Variable_name    | Value |
+------------------+-------+
| have_query_cache | YES   |
+------------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SHOW STATUS LIKE 'Qcache%';
+-------------------------+------------+
| Variable_name           | Value      |
+-------------------------+------------+
| Qcache_free_blocks      | 1          |
| Qcache_free_memory      | 1031832    |
| Qcache_hits             | 0          |
| Qcache_inserts          | 0          |
| Qcache_lowmem_prunes    | 0          |
| Qcache_not_cached       | 3097998155 |
| Qcache_queries_in_cache | 0          |
| Qcache_total_blocks     | 1          |
+-------------------------+------------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Are there any reason why cache is not being used?

Comment: How do you know if it is used or not ? Post query execution check for `Handler` values to determine whether used or not. Moreover, MySQL8+ has deprecated Query Cache because it does more harm than good in present context. InnoDB buffer pool is the way to go.

Comment: Seems like you already have a [solution](https://serverfault.com/a/601979). Does it no longer valid?

Comment: *"MySQL8+ has deprecated Query Cache because it does more harm than good in present context. InnoDB buffer pool is the way to go."* indeed @MadhurBhaiya   [MySQL 8.0: Retiring Support for the Query Cache](https://mysqlserverteam.com/mysql-8-0-retiring-support-for-the-query-cache/) -> *"Although MySQL Query Cache was meant to improve performance, it has serious scalability issues and it can easily become a severe bottleneck."*